# Using break and continue in each() and forEach()

Tags: javascript

I am not sure I understand the value of the functional style looping/mapping if we can't use the break and continue keywords.

I can do this:

```
collections.users.models.forEach(function(item, index) {
    //can't use break or continue...?
});
```

or I can do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < collections.users.models.length; i++) {
     if (user.username === collections.users.models[i].username) {
         app.currentUser = collections.users.models[i];
         break;
     }
}
```

what's the advantage of the functional call if I can't use the break or continue keywords?

Comment: I think there is not advantage at all, actually it is slower in performance [see this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551). I use it because i like the sintax, but I dont think is better than using just javascript

Comment: `forEach` has no "break" or "continue", You can use `some` or `every` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array.prototype.some` and `Array.prototype.every` to continue/break out of functional for loops is a good thing to do

```
[1,2,3,null,5].every(function(v){
    if(!v) return false;  // this will break out of the loop
    // do your regular loopage lulz
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`.each()` or `.forEach()` are less flexible than a plain `for` loop.  They just are.

As you have discovered, they offer you less control over the looping.  They are a convenience ONLY when you want to iterate the entire set or when it really helps you to automatically have a new function context for your loop iteration code (sometimes useful in async operations) or when you enjoy the more declarative coding in that using the method expresses your coding intent a little more clearly and succinctly than the `for` loop.  `.forEach()` will also automatically skip sparse elements of an array.

Other than those features, they are just a reduction in typing that sacrifices some looping control.  Use them when you like one of the advantages and don't use it when you need more looping control.

---

FYI, for Javascript arrays, `.some()` and `.every()` attempt to get you back some looping control, though they are still not as flexible as a `for` loop.

If you use `.some()`, you can `return true;` to be the equivalent of `break;` (since that will stop the looping) and you can just `return;` to be the equivalent of `continue;` (since that will return from the callback and advance to the next iteration).

Comment: Upvote for using `Array.prototype.some` and `Array.prototype.every` to get `break` functionality

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, there is not much of an "advantage" so much as a convenience. You can call `return` to force yourself out of a single iteration of a `forEach` loop, but this is not the same as the native `for` because you are still invoking a function. The convenience comes in the form of not having to define the parameterization of your loop (ie. start point, end point, step size) as well as providing the value of the index and item in the items iterated over.

It is worth mentioning that this convenience comes at the cost of for loop control (ie. start point, end point, step size), backwards iteration, the ability to `break` the entire loop, a small performance impedance, and yes, even cross browser compliance.

Comment: One advantage is that a properly implemented *each* can be more efficient for sparse arrays as it will only iterate over members that exist (similar to for..in), whereas a for loop iterates over all indexes in the range. Not a common case with arrays though.

Answer (score 1):

`each` expresses your intent: to iterate and perform a side effect for each item. `each` abstracts the process of iterating: initializing and incrementing a counter, fetching by array index. That's what the functional combinators do.

Your code snippet is a great example. Let's rewrite that in a functional style:

```
app.currentUser = collections.users.models.find(function (u) {
  return u.username === user.username;
});
```

`find` clearly expresses your intent and abstracts the concept of iterating until you find an item matching your predicate.

Comment: I see what you mean, yes of course, but I don't think you have the syntax right...looks like find is an Underscore.js method?

Comment: I think a better solution would be to pass a function to forEach, that is a more generalized solution, no?

Comment: The syntax looks fine. `find` is a method on `Array.prototype` so maybe your objects are not arrays? You'll have to consult their documentation then. And I'm not sure what you mean by a more generalized solution, or why such a thing is desirable. Using `find` here is very expressive, and much less code as you can see.

Comment: let me take a look at the find() source

Comment: You could try calling `find` directly: `[].find.call(collections.users.models, function (u) { return u.username === user.username; });`

Answer (score 1):

You can't natively break from `forEach` or `each` callback function. However, there is a technique many people use to break from this with customized exception:

```
var BreakException = function(){};

try{
    list.forEach(function(el){
        if (meetCriteria(el)){
            throw BreakException; // Break from forEach
        }
    });
}
catch (e){
    // Catch break
    if (e != BreakException) 
        throw e; // If not a break, but other exceptions, raise it
}

// Carry on
```

Simple approach above is creating a `BreakException` object and raise it whenever you want to break from the unbreakable loop. Catch that particular `BreakException` and carry on what your function does.

One thing to remember, *always check if the caught exception is BreakException* as you defined, since the other possible exceptions (like TypeError, etc) also got trapped by this catch statement. Don't swallow it without checking.

Comment: Why would you do this over using a for loop?

Comment: This just copes with the OP's doubt on how to break from `forEach` or `each`. However, in case you need to avoid native `for..in` or `for..of` loop (perhaps by the coding convention guideline of the project or something), and you want to break whenever the remaining elements are no longer needed for processing. Using `exception` to mimic `break` is easy and doesn't destroy code's readability.

Comment: I forget to add "hopefully". :)