# splitting a string into a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, object

I have a list of strings, I want to check if the string contains a specific word, and if it does split all the words in the string and add it to an associative array.

```
myString = ['RT @Arsenal: Waiting for the international', 'We’re hungry for revenge @_nachomonreal on Saturday\'s match and aiming for a strong finish']

wordtoFind = ['@Arsenal']
```

I want to loop through the `wordtoFind` and if it is in `myString`, split up `myString` into individual words and create an object like

```
newWord = {@Arsenal:[{RT:1},{Waiting:1},{for:1},{the:1},{international:1}]}

for(z=0; z <wordtoFind.length; z++){
  for ( i = 0 ; i < myString.length; i++) {
    if (myString[i].indexOf(wordtoFind[z].key) > -1){
      myString[i].split(" ")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your newWord is not a valid object.

Comment: Can you clarify? I don't understand what you want to create. Effectively, the objet is not valid (what are the keys or {waiting:1},  {for:1}, etc. ?
And you want all the words into objects like {word:1}? Can you explain?

Comment: So you want to count each of the words in your string?

Comment: @NinaScholz I have edited the question,  is this a valid object ?

Comment: @Vincent  sorry I am new to javascript but what i want is the main key is wordtoFind which maps onto the words in newWord and their occurrence in myString

Comment: @PostCrafter yes the occurrence of the word in the string should be its count.

Comment: Just another questions, does it have to match a word or just be in the string?
`@Arsenal` matches `@Arsenal:`  as a string, but not as a word, it also matches `@Arsenal123`

Comment: @PostCrafter it needs to match the entire word. I am going to do some preprocessing to remove punctuations. It should not match "@Arsenall123"

Answer (score 2):

I would say something likes would work, this also counts the amount of occurrences of a word in a sentence. JavaScript does not have associative arrays like `PHP` for instance. They just have `objects` or numbered `arrays`:

```
var myString = ['RT @Arsenal: Waiting for the international', 'We’re hungry for revenge @_nachomonreal on Saturday\'s match and aiming for a strong finish'];

var wordtoFind = ['@Arsenal'];

var result = {};

for(var i = 0, l = wordtoFind.length; i < l; i++) {

    for(var ii = 0, ll = myString.length; ii < ll; ii++) {
        if(myString[ii].indexOf(wordtoFind[i]) !== -1) {
            var split = myString[ii].split(' ');
            var resultpart = {};
            for(var iii = 0, lll = split.length; iii < lll; iii++) {
                if(split[iii] !== wordtoFind[i]) {
                    if(!resultpart.hasOwnProperty(split[iii])) {
                      resultpart[split[iii]] = 0;
                    }
                    resultpart[split[iii]]++;
                }
            }
            result[wordtoFind[i]] = resultpart;
        }
    }
}

console.log(result); 
//{"@Arsenal":{"RT":1,"Waiting":1,"for":1,"the":1,"international":1}}
```

Comment: thanks for this but I got a comment saying that result was not a valid object. I have now edited the question, how would this change the answer? Thanks @PierreDuc

Comment: @qwertyayyy Is there a reason you want it to be an array? My answer generates a valid object as well. If you check the output from the `console.log` you can see what it is. It would change my answer in such a way that it makes it harder (but not impossible) to count for the amount of occurrences

Comment: @PierreDuuc Sorry I am new to Javascript and I just got a comment saying it was an invalid object that all. But thank you for the answer

Comment: @qwertyayyy Well, in that case, i am sure that my answer will suffice your needs :)

Comment: how do I access individual elements in the result object ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This method makes use of the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)-function and callbacks.
The containsWord-function was left with a for-loop for now to reduce some callbacks, this can obviously be changed.

```
var myString = [
    'RT @Arsenal: Waiting for the international',
    'We’re hungry for revenge @_nachomonreal on Saturday\'s match and aiming for a strong finish',
    '@Arsenal: one two three four two four three four three four'
];

var wordtoFind = ['@Arsenal'];

// define the preprocessor that is used before the equality check
function preprocessor(word) {
    return word.replace(':', '');
}

function findOccurences(array, search, callback, preprocessor) {
    var result = {};
    var count = 0;
    // calculate the maximum iterations
    var max = search.length * array.length;
    // iterate the search strings that should be matched
    search.forEach(function(needle) {
        // iterate the array of strings that should be searched in
        array.forEach(function(haystack) {
            if (containsWord(haystack, needle, preprocessor)) {
                var words = haystack.split(' ');
                // iterate every word to count the occurences and write them to the result
                words.forEach(function(word) {
                    countOccurence(result, needle, word);
                })
            }
            count++;
            // once every iteration finished, call the callback
            if (count == max) {
                callback && callback(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

function containsWord(haystack, needle, preprocessor) {
    var words = haystack.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i];
        // preprocess a word before it's compared
        if (preprocessor) {
            word = preprocessor(word);
        }
        // if it matches return true
        if (word === needle) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function countOccurence(result, key, word) {
    // add array to object if it doesn't exist yet
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result[key] = [];
    }
    var entry = result[key];
    // set the count to 0 if it doesn't exist yet
    if (!entry.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
        entry[word] = 0;
    }
    entry[word]++;
}

// call our function to find the occurences
findOccurences(myString, wordtoFind, function(result) {
    // do something with the result
    console.log(result);
}, preprocessor);

// output:
/*
 { '@Arsenal':
   [ RT: 1,
    '@Arsenal:': 2,
    Waiting: 1,
    for: 1,
    the: 1,
    international: 1,
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4 ] }
 */
```

Feel free to ask any questions, if the answer needs clarification.

I hope this fits your needs.

Comment: You took it to the next level ;). But a little remark though, `forEach` is not an `asynchronous` function.

Comment: @PierreDuc correct, I haven't been using this too much lately, it's blocking obviously. Also thanks for the edit to the english documentation, haven't even noticed that google led me to the german version. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  You just need to store the split string into the associative array variable.

```
var assocArr = [];
for(z=0; z <wordtoFind.length; z++){
     for ( i = 0 ; i < myString.length; i++) {
         if (myString[i].indexOf(wordtoFind[z]) > -1){

             myString[i].split(" ").forEach(function(word){
                 assocArr.push(word);
             });

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: the .key is not working in the if statement - use it like this:   if (myString[i].indexOf(wordtoFind[z]) > -1){.....

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I get for copy pasting I guess :/

Answer (score 0):

I think the key problem that stuck you is the data structure. The optimal structure should be something like this:

```
{
    @Arsenal:[
        {RT:1, Waiting:1, for:1, the:1, international:1},
        {xxx:1, yyy:1, zzz:3}, //for there are multiple ones in 'myString' that contain the same '@Arsenal'
        {slkj:1, sldjfl:2, lsdkjf:1} //maybe more
    ]
    someOtherWord:[
        {},
        {},
        ....
    ]
}
```

And the code:

```
var result = {};

//This function will return an object like {RT:1, Waiting:1, for:1, the:1, international:1}.
function calculateCount(string, key) {
    var wordCounts = {};
    string.split(" ").forEach(function (word) {
        if (word !== key) {
            if (wordCounts[word] === undefined) wordCounts[word] = 1;
            else wordCounts[word]++;
        }
    });
    return wordCounts;
}

//For each 'word to find' and each string that contain the 'word to find', push in that returned object {RT:1, Waiting:1, for:1, the:1, international:1}.
wordToFind.forEach(function (word) {
    var current = result[word] = [];
    myString.forEach(function (str) {
        if (str.indexOf(word) > -1) {
            current.push(
                calculateCount(str, word)
            );
        }
    });  //Missed the right parenthesis here
});
```

Comment: Hi I am getting a syntax error from the statement "continue" @Yan-Yang

Comment: @qwertyayyy I'm sorry. I made a mistake. I modified the code and it's ok now. `continue` can't be used in `forEach`. Here is a question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016841/using-break-and-continue-in-each-and-foreach

Comment: Im sorry but how do I output this to the console. It just returning an empty list. @Yan-Yang

Comment: I missed a right parenthesis just now. I have added it. And I used `wordToFind` not `wordtoFind`. Also, to output to the console, use `console.dir(result);`.

Comment: I have tested in my console using your example of `myString` and `wordtoFind`. The result is `@Arsenal: Array[1] [ 0: Object {@Arsenal:: 1, RT: 1, Waiting: 1, for: 1, international: 1, the: 1}]`

Comment: `@Arsenal:` was not omitted because it's different than `@Arsenal`.